# VBA Ambiguous name detected error

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, vba

I am trying to use VBA programming for Excel. What is happening is when I try to run this program I get this error and I do not under stand what it means?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You try to define a function within a sub, it isn't possible in VBA.

Comment: What is another approach?

Comment: Define the function after the sub (function... Statement after end sub line), what is your reason to define it within the sub?

Comment: Well what my goal was to have this formula in my personal file and call it in any excel file when ever I want. But I cant quite figure out how to do that

Comment: Also I see just now that probably also your previous function is called overfour, you can have just one function with one name.

Comment: I Changed it but same error still

Answer (score 1):

Simple words explanation:

`sub four()` must have a corresponding `end sub` before
the line that begins with `Function OverFour(...`

Comment: I did that but then the my function wont run? comes up with the same eror

Comment: https://translate.google.se/?hl=en&tab=wT#en/hu/ambiguous - you have used the same name for at least two things (example: function, sub). What that is - is not clear from the image you have provided.